# Set "Path" environment variable during vsts build so it would persist across build tasks specifically vsTest task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, vstest

I have a vsts build definition in which I try to set the PATH environment variable using PowerShell (and before I tried cmd) task, so that in a later vsTest task, the tests could run an exe from that path, however setting the PATH using the ps\cmd tasks doesn’t seem to work, I tried a few options such as:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";" + $newPath, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)

setx path " %newPath;%PATH%"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Environment variables are usually inherited by sub-processes, but processes that are invoked in succession won't be able to pick up the values that way. You may be able set a file that can be queried in your later test task to get the PATH you need.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set the process environment variable by calling [logging command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) through PowerShell task:

For example:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]${env:PATH};$newPath";
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing just that

Comment: Btw, this is not working properly if you're injecting a secret variable that contains a dollar sign in its value. The dollar signs are removed from the final value. I came across this specific problem when injecting a secret connection string containing a dollar sign.

Comment: Make sure you _don't_ add `isOutput=true` as parameter to `task.setvariable` - it didn't work for me then.

Comment: How should one use this in Kudu for an azure function? I get:
$newPath = "D:\home\python364x86"
PS D:\home> Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]${env:PATH};$newPath";
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]${env:PATH};$newPath";
Write-Host : The Win32 internal error "The handle is invalid" 0x6 occurred

Answer (score 5):

If you need to do this in a Linux pipeline you can do the following:

`- script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]${PATH}:<your new path here>"`