# How to get Azure Pipelines to recognize JavaFX dependency with Gradle

Tags: java, azure, gradle, javafx-8, azure-pipelines

I have been unable to get Azure Pipelines to run the way I am expecting.

The project codebase is in Java, version 8 and is using the JavaFX Library.

I am trying to introduce continuous integration via Azure Pipelines. To do this I decided to use Gradle to manage project dependencies.

Here is the gradle.build file I am using to declare project dependencies.

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    id 'java'

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre'
    implementation 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins:javafx-gradle-plugin:8.8.2'

    // Use JUnit Jupiter API for testing.
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2'

    // Use JUnit Jupiter Engine for testing.
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.2'
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClassName = 'main.java.application.App'
}

test {
    // Use junit platform for unit tests
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

This is the error I except when I run my pipeline. This is a run from my computer.

```
Code\SNR-Project\Anature> ./gradlew build

>Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-bin.zip
>.........10%.........20%.........30%..........40%.........50%
>.........60%..........70%.........80%.........90%.........100%
>
>Welcome to Gradle 6.1.1!
>
>Here are the highlights of this release:
> 
> - Reusable dependency cache
> - Configurable compilation order between Groovy/Kotlin/Java/Scala
> - New sample projects in Gradle's documentation
>
>For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/release-notes.html
>
>Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
>
> Task :compileTestJava FAILED
>
>Code\SNR-Project\Anature\src\test\java\applicationTests\AppTest.java:16: error: >cannot find symbol
>        asserNotNull(classUnderTest.getGreeting(), "app should have a greeting");
>        ^
>  symbol:   method asserNotNull(String,String)
>  location: class AppTest
>1 error
>
>FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
>* What went wrong:
>Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
>* Try:
>Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug >option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
>* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
>BUILD FAILED in 31s
>6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
```

Here is the error I am getting in when I run the pipeline. This is a run in a Microsoft hosted VM.

```
>##[section]Starting: Gradle
>==============================================================================
>Task         : Gradle
>Description  : Build using a Gradle wrapper script
>Version      : 2.163.0
>Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>Help         : >https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle
>==============================================================================
>SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
>[command]/home/vsts/work/1/s/Anature/gradlew --refresh-dependencies build
>Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-bin.zip
>.........10%.........20%.........30%..........40%.........50%
>.........60%..........70%.........80%.........90%.........100%
> 
>Welcome to Gradle 6.1.1!
> 
>Here are the highlights of this release:
>  - Reusable dependency cache
>  - Configurable compilation order between Groovy/Kotlin/Java/Scala
>  - New sample projects in Gradle's documentation
> 
> For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/release-notes.html
> 
> Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> 
> > Task :compileJava
> /home/vsts/work/1/s/Anature/src/main/java/application/Player.java:5: error: >package javafx.scene.image does not exist
> import javafx.scene.image.Image;
>                          ^
> /home/vsts/work/1/s/Anature/src/main/java/application/Player.java:12: error: >cannot find symbol
>   private Image sprite; 
>           ^
>   symbol:   class Image
>   location: class Player
> 2 errors
> 
> > Task :compileJava FAILED
> 
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> 
> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -->debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> 
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> 
> BUILD FAILED in 14s
> 1 actionable task: 1 executed
> Error: The process '/home/vsts/work/1/s/Anature/gradlew' failed with exit >code 1
>     at ExecState._setResult (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94->4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.163.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task->lib/toolrunner.js:816:25)
>     at ExecState.CheckComplete (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94->4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.163.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task->lib/toolrunner.js:799:18)
>     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94->4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.163.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task->lib/toolrunner.js:721:19)
>     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
>     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)
> No test result files matching /home/vsts/work/1/s/**/TEST-*.xml were found, >so publishing JUnit test results is being skipped.
> ##[error]Error: The process '/home/vsts/work/1/s/Anature/gradlew' failed with >exit code 1
> ##[section]Finishing: Gradle
```

So the issue is that in the Pipeline it's throwing an error saying that a JavaFX import does not exist. When in theory

```
./gradle build
```

should be installing the required libraries on the Microsoft VM to run the code.

Just in case anyone is interested here is my azure-pipelines.yaml

```
trigger:
  - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: 'Anature/gradlew'
    workingDirectory: 'Anature'
    options: '--refresh-dependencies' 
    tasks: 'build'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
```

Here you can see I am trying to force install all the dependencies but still am getting a

```
package javafx.scene.image does not exist
```

Here are some reference links:

For Azure Gradle task.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops

Azure VM Specs:
https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md

Gradle dependency information:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html

**Update:**

I had to first figure out what an azure pipeline VM had stock on it and why JavaFX wasn't working.

Here is a link to the download Java 1.8 version that comes stock on the Azure VM.

http://repos.azul.com/azure-only/zulu/packages/zulu-8/8u222/

Once you download the Zulu package for java you will see that JavaFX was not apart of the Java download like it is for the Java JDK.

Comment: Please avoid links to (code-)screenshots and post your code directly in your question.

Comment: @Neo I got rid of the images. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Please try to set system.debug to True and share the entire log.

Comment: @HunterMatthewRich Have you tried to install `openjfx`? Is it working?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I will try that this week. I was doing some research on what comes stock on the VM and will update my post with my findings later this week as well.

Comment: @HunterMatthewRich Is your issue solved after you use chocolatey to install the java jdk and switch to windows-latest VM?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to install `openjfx` to see whether the issue persists:

`sudo apt-get install openjfx`

Comment: I was not able to get that to work. I think it might be a Path variable problem. Since the previous Java 1.8 bin is still in the Path. I am using chocolatey to install the java jdk instead of the openjfx and I have switched to windows-latest VM instead of using ubuntu.

Comment: Is your issue solved after you use chocolatey to install the java jdk and switch to windows-latest VM?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is what worked for me.

- Install chocolatey from Azure MarketPlace
- Add chocolatey as task to install jdk8
- Add PS Task with the commands below to adjust path variables

´´´

```
$newpath = “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211”
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]${env:PATH};$newPath";
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=JAVA_HOME;]$newPath";
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=JDK_18_x64;]$newPath";
```

´´´

The persistent change of the environment variables is a bit of a pain because there is a lot of information around that just does not help in this scenario. What finally helped me was this post here:

[Set "Path" environment variable during vsts build so it would persist across build tasks specifically vsTest task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49288558/set-path-environment-variable-during-vsts-build-so-it-would-persist-across-bui)